# How do I format both a string and variable in an f-string?

Tags: python, f-string

I'm trying to move both the "$" and totalTransactionCost to the right side of the field.

My current code is : `print(f"Total Cost Of All Transactions: ${totalTransactionCost:>63,.2f}")`

The code is able to move the totalTransactionCost to the right side of the field, but how can I include the "$" too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use nested f-strings, which basically divides formatting into two steps: first, format the number as a comma-separated two-decimal string, and attach the `$`, and then fill the whole string with leading spaces.

```
>>> totalTransactionCost = 10000
>>> print(f"Total Cost Of All Transactions: {f'${totalTransactionCost:,.2f}':>64}")
Total Cost Of All Transactions:                                                       $10,000.00
```

Comment: An explanation would enrich the answer

Answer (score 1):

[f-string](https://fstring.help/) offers flexibility.
If the currency is determined by the system, `locale` allows leveraging the system's setting: [LC_MONETARY](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.LC_MONETARY) for currency

Below is a `f-string` walkthrough

```py
## input value or use default
totalTransactionCost = input('enter amount e.g 50000') or '50000'

## OP's code:
#print(f"Total Cost Of All Transactions: ${totalTransactionCost:>63,.2f}")

## f-string with formatting
## :,.2f  || use thousand separator with 2 decimal places
## :>63 || > aligns right with 63 spaces
## :<      || < aligns left
## { ... :,.2f} apply to inner f-string value
## {f'${ ... }':>64}  || apply to outer f-string value

print(f'|Total Cost of All Transactions|: {f"${int(totalTransactionCost):,.2f}":>64}')

## Note that the inner and outer uses different escapes. 
## The order doesn't matter though. Here, inner is " and outer is '.
```

```
|enter amount e.g 50000| 750000
Total Cost of All Transactions:                                                      $750,000.00
```